# How to make one shortcut to execute .cpp file

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, sublime-text

whenever I want to execute a .cpp in terminal I have to write ./ before it .

And I want to change this "./" to something else .

I found this on another thread :

```
cr(){
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: cr <file.cpp>"
else
    name=$(echo $1 | cut -f 1 -d '.')
    g++ $1 -o name; ./name
fi
```

}

It works fine but the thing is that I want to use it with flags like -DLOCAL and some others, how do I make it work?

Because right now I'm using sublime text with some templates and those (templates) require the flags to show the values in terminal .

And also if there is a way to make it work without writing the .cpp extension everytime

```
(ex : cr A.cpp in cr A)
```

Thanks !

Edit : Managed to get the flags working but still, is there a way to not write .cpp when running the shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

The command `make A` will compile and link a `A.cpp` using default rule `g++     A.cpp   -o A`

Ex. given

```
$ cat > A.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(void) { std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl; return 0; }
```

then

```
$ make A
g++     A.cpp   -o A

$ ./A
Hello world
```